# Can we duplicate the titles of Liferay's OOTB portlets?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am talking about the Add menu which appears for admins on the left hand side.

The requirement is that we want Liferay's portlet say, `Blogs` portlet to appear not only in the `Collaboration` category but also in a custom category say, `Test Portlets` with a different name like `Test Blogs`.

Also when the User adds the portlet `Test Blogs` then the title of the portlet on the page should also be `Test Blogs`.

Is this possible?

Why I want to do this?
Because we are using [Application Adapters](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/application-adapter-hook-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en) to customize some of Liferay's OOTB portlets and we want a different name for them in few sites.

It will be fine even if the portlet can be moved to a separate category with different name in few sites.

Thanks for any help in this direction.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't any provision readily available, you may override `portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\layout_configuration\view_category.jsp` , in order to achieve this requirement.